# Extract single True/False value from JSON Twitter response ( Tweepy and Python )

Tags: python, arrays, json, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to write a little bit of code in an app that checks if a user is following you or not. I just want the code to return a True/False value that I can put in an if loop.

The code is:

```
user_id = '1234567890'
print api.show_friendship(target_id=user_id)
```

And it returns all this JSON, which I know nothing about but want the 'false' value from the second array for the other user under 'following' (or, alternatively, the true/false from the first array under 'followed_by'... either way is fine!):

```
{"relationship":{"source":{"id":0000000000,"id_str":"0000000000","screen_name":"auth_user","following":false,"followed_by":false,"following_received":false,"following_requested":false,"notifications_enabled":false,"can_dm":false,"blocking":false,"blocked_by":false,"muting":false,"want_retweets":false,"all_replies":false,"marked_spam":false},"target":{"id":123456789,"id_str":"123456789","screen_name":"other_user","following":false,"followed_by":false,"following_received":false,"following_requested":false}}}
```

How can I make my code return the true/false for the "following":false part?

(or, the "followed_by":false part in the first array - each array is from the user's "viewpoint" of the relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, solved it immediately after posting.

Try:

```
print json.loads(api.show_friendship(target_id=user_id))["relationship"]["target"]["followed_by"]
```

You can work through the JSON array by specifying each branch as you go through it (I'm sure many people know that lol, but I've never used JSON!)...

Answer (score 0):

```
print api.show_friendship(target_screen_name=screen_name)[1].following
```

True